# ASP .NET how can i add a dropdownlist into a table column after clicking on a button that create new table row?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Here is my code(currently when the add button is clicked, it will only generate a new row but when clicked again it wont work and i have to make it constantly add new row. And on the cell1 to cell6, all the text should be replaced based on the first line of the table) can someone who are expert on this please please please please help me?

```
    <%@ Page Title="Edit" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" 
     AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Edit.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

 <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" 
 ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
 </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
```

### Edit

void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

```
         if (!IsPostBack)
         {
             Button1.Click += new EventHandler(this.Adds);
         }
         
     }

     void Adds(Object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
  
         TableRow row = new TableRow();
         TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
         TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
         TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
         TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
         TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();
         TableCell cell6 = new TableCell();
         
         //DropDownList ddl = (row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList);
         cell1.Text = "asas";
         cell2.Text = "asass";
         cell3.Text = "asasss";
         cell4.Text = "asassss";
         cell5.Text = "asasssss";
         cell6.Text = "asassssss";
         row.Cells.Add(cell1);
         row.Cells.Add(cell2);
         row.Cells.Add(cell3);
         row.Cells.Add(cell4);
         row.Cells.Add(cell5);
         row.Cells.Add(cell6);
         myTable.Rows.Add(row);

         
     }
     
     </script>


<p class = "firstClass">123456</p> 
<p class = "secondClass">John Wick</p>
<asp:button ID = "Button1" Text = "Add" runat = "server" OnClick ="Adds" style = float:right />

<asp:Table ID="myTable" runat = "server" Width = "100%">
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>Application Key</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>Notes</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>Create</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>Update</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>View</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>Delete</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Google Chrome" Value="Google Chrome"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Internet Explorer" Value="Internet Explorer"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yahoo" Value="Yahoo"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Firefox" Value="Firefox"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server"/></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server" CssClass="Checkboxs" /></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" CssClass="Checkboxs"/></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" CssClass="Checkboxs"/></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" CssClass="Checkboxs"/></asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

```
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You should use gridview. And also switching to asp.net mvc will be more beneficial in long run

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i had changed to asp.net mvc already and how do i implement gridview? @Chetan

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/insertupdatedelete-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-using-ado-net/

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/MVC-WebGrid-CRUD-Select-Insert-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-WebGrid-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: all these can work on microsoft visual studio 2010? @Chetan

Comment: Which version of .net framework and asp.net mvc you are using? They should work. Did you try?

Comment: i am using visual studio 2010 and 2.0 mvc. i tried but it seems like there are many terms are missing from my side @Chetan